# Are polymorphic associations necessary?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, foreign-keys, polymorphic-associations

I am a rails newbie struggling to understand the advantage of using a polymorphic association over multiple belongs_to declarations with associated foreign keys.  In Ryan Bates' railscast (http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association-revised), for example, *articles*, *events* and *photos* can each have many *comments*, so he sets up a polymorphic association using *commentable*.

Why not just have *comments* belong to each of the other three assets and include *article_id*, *event_id* and *photo_id* foreign keys in its table where only one will be non-null?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do that, but there will be disadvantages. Some that I can think of:

1. Sparse table with many nulls
2. No separation of concerns. Comments has to change whenever you add a commentable model
3. Rails already supports polymorphic associations and makes it easy to use them. So why not?

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't thought of separation of concerns.  (Sorry that I don't have enough reps to vote up.)